# C# - Trying to convert string (with HEX) to display extended ASCII chars in TextBox

Tags: c#, encoding, hex, ascii

I am trying to take a string with hex `FFFFFFFF7DA98035` and display its extended ASCII characters in a TextBox in my program.  I am having problems with 80 as its -128 and displays nothing.

Visual Studio compiles without errors, but throws an exception when it parses the string.

```
private static string ConvertHextoAscii(string HexString)
{
    byte[] data = new byte[HexString.Length / 2];

    for (int i = 0; i < HexString.Length - 1; i += 2)
    {
        data[i / 2] = byte.Parse(HexString.Substring(i, 2));
    }

    return Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252").GetString(data);
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what is the actual exception thrown?

Comment: https://ideone.com/WDA0ue check this code

Comment: "FFFFFFFF7DA98035" does not contain enough sensible "extended ASCII characters" and does not represent a string in any human language.  Only using BitConverter.ToString(data) can produce something recognizable.

Answer (score 2):

`byte.Parse` is expecting a string that contains an integer (in decimal). However, `HexString.Substring(i, 2)` will return a hex number (as a string).

Do the following to instruct `byte.Parse` to expect a hex number:

```
data[i / 2] = byte.Parse(HexString.Substring(i, 2), NumberStyles.HexNumber);
```

Comment: `Convert.ToByte(HexString.Substring(i, 2), 16);`